# How can I get an automatic alert by SMS or mail when my office computer is on/off?

Tags: windows, alert

How can I get an automatic alert by SMS or mail when my Windows office computer is logged onto/off of?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a command line tool like [blat](http://www.blat.net/) or [bmail](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm). You then create a batch script (*.bat) for sending the mails. This could be triggered by just putting it in your startup folder or for a nicer way, see this question: [How to schedule a task to run when shutting down windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows)

> if you want to add a Startup/Shutdown script, you need to be looking for Windows Settings under Computer Configuration. If you want to add a Logon/Logoff script, you need to be looking for Windows Settings under User Configuration.
>
> For Startup/Shutdown:
>
> Run gpedit.msc (Local Policies)
>   Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Startup or Shutdown -> Properties -> Add
>
> For Logon/Logoff:
>
> Run gpedit.msc (Local Policies)
>   User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Logon or Logoff -> Properties -> Add